# MongoDB C# driver: connect directly to shard

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-.net-driver, sharding

Is there a way in MongoDB (via mongo shell or C# driver) to get list of all shards from mongos, but then communicate to shards directly (at least for reading data), and get all (or partial) data from each shard individually?